# How to save `None` value in a dict to redis in Python?

Tags: python, redis

I am using `redis==3.3.8` in my python application to talk with `redis`. And I use `redis.mset` to save a python dict on redis. However, I got this error if there is a `None` value in my dict:

`redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'NoneType'. Convert to a byte, string or number first.`.

I wonder how I can save `None` value into redis without converting?

Comment: Looks like redis doesn't support `None`, you have to convert. Which should be pretty clear from the error message... https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/1071

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide what is an appropriate `null` value in your case.

An empty string, '', may work for you.

```
data = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': None,
}
# convert None to ''
converted_data = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    converted_data[k] = v if v is not None else ''
REDIS.mset(converted_data)
```

Comment: Empty string works for me but do I have to convert before save to redis?